# unexpected T_SL from Caused by Git 

Tags: git

I am now making changes directly on my ftp server so I created a remote repository on my ftp server and attempted to push to origin, the same repository I was pushing to on my local machine.

I got a non-fast forward error, and attempted to do a pull request, I got "warning no common commits"  I ended up with this error on my site "unexpected T_SL"

GIT inserted <<

[image]

Comment: Could you rather clone your ftp repo locally, make or report your changes there, and then push?

Comment: I am making changes directly on the server because I am working from multiple locations.  Would a clone to my server overrwrite the changes I have there?

Comment: The problem with making changes directly on the server is to generate a divergent history from the local repo. The simplest way to get back in sync is to clone the server repo, report any local modifications on the local clone, and then push back to the server repo.

Comment: what do you mean by "report any local modifications on the local clone"

Comment: I mean that you already have a first local repo in which yu made some commits. Since that local repo is hopelessly out of sync with the remote ftp one, I suggest to clone that ftp repo as a second local repo, reports the files (with a simple third-party file comparison tool) in that second local repo, and then push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `T_SL` error is PHP telling it found a `<<<<<<` conflict marker inserted by Git.

```
fgrep -R . '<<<<<'
```

will find all such files.

If you want to keep your local changes, you'll need to resolve those conflicts (either manually or via `git mergetool`), commit them and pull from that repo.

If you want to get rid of local changes, do `git reset --hard` or safer, `git stash`, which will save those changes in a stash (you can get it back with `git stash pop`).